# django admin edit form not getting file value

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin, django-uploads

In my html i have a code like :

```
<div class="col-md-4 form-group">
    <label for="file1">License<span class="req">*</span></label><br>
    {% if data.data.licence %}
    <p class="file-upload">Currently: <a
            href="/media/{{data.data.licence}}">{{data.data.licence}}</a>
        <br>
        Change:
        <input type="file" name="licence" accept="image/*" id="licence">
    </p>
    {%else%}
    <input type="file" required name="licence" id="licence">
    {%endif%}
</div>
```

and in my code i am getting value like :

```
document = request.FILES['licence']
```

but i am not getting the value in edit form cae whem i am doing this can anyone please help me related this ?? i dont know what i am doing wrong here in my code my add code is working fine where i am getting value from the form and saving data in db like :

```
vendor/licence/ticket.png
```

Comment: is the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is present in the html?

Comment: Yes i have already added this on my add and edit form.

Comment: @BenBoyer is there any solution ? why i am not getting value in edit section